# Allow users to access their page on my site by using their own custom domain

Tags: php, server, dns

I'm building a PHP MYSQL based site builder based on smarty templates where each site would have a folder which would contain all the site files such as html, assets and scripts. I want to add a option for my users to add their domain name in the backend for each site, point a dns record to my server and be able to access their folder on the server via their domain name

For example their url on my site would be www.sitebuilder.com/sites/example/
Their domain: www.exampledomain.com

When someone visits this domain, the index.html at the url would be shown.

I hope this makes sense, How do i achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that PHP alone will get you what you want. Some of this is down to the web server in use. See [this page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html) for how Apache handles it. You would need a dedicated server to do this. Doable, and not necessarily expensive.

Comment: The server will run apache! Ill take a look! Trying to get my head wrapped around this, thank you!